# Can't retrieve user id after successful Facebook authentication

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am having trouble to authenticate users through the Facebook PHP SDK.

Basically I want to show a "log in with facebook" button if the user is not already authenticated. Otherwise, present the user name. Here is the code:

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => 'XXX',
        'secret' => 'XXX',
        'cookie' => true
));
$userId = $facebook->getUser();
var_dump($userId);
if ($userId) {
    $userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId);
    echo "Welcome, {$userInfo['name']}";
} else {
    echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">' .
'<img src="images/icon_facebook_login.png" alt="Login with Facebook" /></a>';
}
```

The trouble is I always get 0 from `$facebook->getUser()`. I looked at the code in `base_facebook.php` and while processing the function a request param `signed_request` is expected in the return URL. The only params I see in the URL Facebook returns are `code` and `state`.

Any ideas what I might have messed up? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** As suggested by `ogi` I made a hand-made request with the `code` param to `graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` and I did receive `access_token`. Now, the only question remaining is how to accomplish this through the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I didn't copy `fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt` file to the directory where `facebook.php` and `base_facebook.php` reside. In `getAccessTokenFromCode()` the code to `facebook.com/oauth/access_token...` fails but since they capture the exception, it is very hard to figure out.

Hopefully this will save someone some hours of code tracing.

Answer (score 2):

Canvas apps (apps on Facebook) always receive a `signed_request` from the top frame --from Facebook.

External websites don't. They get a `code` back after the user approves the app, which apparently you also do.

The last bit of authentication is exchanging the `code` for an `access_token`, which is something you should test yourself. So get the code from the request, and try the following in your browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
   client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
   client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&code=THE_CODE
```

(for `redirect_uri` use the same url that's not getting a userid)

See what you get. Then post an update to your question, and we'll see :-)

**EDIT**

In case you're not doing it, it's important to have php display all errors while you're developing:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

(in your php.ini)

The last bit of authentication uses `curl` to get the access token over https. I'm not a curl expert, but this can help overcome ssl problems:

```
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;
Facebook::$CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST] = 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ori. I receive the `access_token`. Now, how to make this request through the PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

please change this line to this

```
$userInfo = $facebook->api('/' . $userId);
```

change to

```
$userInfo = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Because you are using outh of your api not another one.

then

try to

```
echo $userInfo['id']
```

or you can use this one full control

```
    <?php
    require 'fb/facebook.php';

    // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId' => 'xxx',
      'secret' => 'xxx',
    ));

    // Get User ID
    $user = $facebook->getUser();

    // We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
    //
    // If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
    // Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
    // token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }


echo '<pre>';
print_r($user_profile);

    ?>
```

Comment: `getUser()` always returns 0. With your example, too, which is basically the same.

Comment: i am using this as it is on my website, and its showing me fb user exact id... please re generate your secrete key or check session really started... and also check your key...